# Quotation marks, commas and brackets, the best way to approach it for a comprehensive dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text

I received multiple files to load into dataframes and perform some analysis.
Text is still my weak spot, I always stray to other types of data.
The text file includes the name of several drugs and a label indicating if they exist in a particular country by that name or not. (drug names have different nomenclature in different countries)

The text file presents itself in the following format:

```
medicine_nomenclature, "availability"
{wellbutrin}, false
{daflon}, true
{modafinil}, true
{vigantol}, false
{vigantol, bioactive}, false
```

If you have any suggestions or documentation on what what be the best approach it would be absolutely awesome.
Thank you for your time (and happy weekend)!

edit: the size of the file is roughly 109 KB with about 3000 rows

Comment: how big each of those file?

Comment: @deadvoid just added an edit with this info, it has about 3000 rows and 100 KB, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 109KB would take long for string removals

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

removal = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(list('{}"')))

with open('drugs.csv') as drugs:
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(drugs.read().translate(removal)))

print(df)

  medicine_nomenclature  availability
0            wellbutrin         false
1                daflon          true
2             modafinil          true
3              vigantol         false
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I had tried something similar, but unfortunately whenever I have more than one element inside the curly brackets it returns a tokenization error. I am sure in the end it is something super trivial, can't get over the hump. From what I can see it is a data entry error so sometimes they put multiple drugs under the same label. I guess that further down I can string explode to try to get the listed items in one cell be their own row. Head is mush today.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you have multiple drug names separated with comma within the curly bracket then with this route you have to use regex.

Comment: That is my struggle, I can't find a delimiter that does not return errors, I originally was going with: ``` drugs = pd.read_csv(drugs_file, sep = ",",  names = ['drug', 'availability' ``` and that is when I found this issue, I mean, I can load this on excel and manually fix it but that will void any learning I can get from this. Actually, now that I think about it, is there any way to define the delimiter as only the last comma?

Comment: by definition the delimiter/separator is to denote every column. I think for this one it's not hard to use regex, just a bit tedious. Do you know regex? If there's only a single file, it can be done in other way too.

Comment: I know the basics, just never applied them in the context of making a dataframe. For a second I thought I could use something like this: ```rows = []

with open(drugs_file) as f:
    
    keys = next(f).split(',')
    for line in f:
        rows.append(dict(zip(keys, line.split(',', -1))))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows) ``` as a way to delimit only at the last comma and then I would deal with the curly braces after using findall or something like that. I feel like I am getting closer lmao, you are an amazing place to bounce ideas off of because I had been looking at this in a blank

Comment: nah, it always helps to externalize the questions & thoughts, it's the core idea behind rubber duck debugging & brainstorming :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207433/discussion-between-bls-and-deadvoid).